# Encounter tput: unknown terminal "emacs" in PyCharm while Using PySpark on MacOS Yosemite

Tags: python, emacs, pycharm, pyspark

I am configuring PyCharm for linking pyspark according to [this link](http://blog.markajones.co.uk/2014/11/how-to-debug-apache-spark-job-using.html). PyCharm successfully found the package and auto-completed my codes.

However, when I run the code by calling `python demo1.py` in the terminal, I got the following info:

```
tput: unknown terminal "emacs" 
49886
```

I guess it has something to do with my terminal (bash) setting. But I am too ignorant to solve the problem.

**update:**

When I created a SparkContext in an IPyhton terminal window by running:

```
In [1]: from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

In [2]: sc = SparkContext()
50463
```

The terminal gave me some random number (port number?) and the terminal froze. So I think the problem is not due to PyCharm.

Comment: *"when I run the code by calling python demo1.py in the terminal"* -- which terminal would that be? Are you running this inside Emacs?

Comment: I simply ran `python demo1.py` in bash. Not in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tried it again and it works. In particular, in a bash terminal I opened ipython:

```
ipython
```

Then, in ipython call:

```
In [1]: from pyspark import SparkContext

In [2]: sc = SparkContext()
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/08/26 10:39:49 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.1
15/08/26 10:39:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/08/26 10:39:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: 
15/08/26 10:39:50 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: 
15/08/26 10:39:50 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(panc25); users with modify permissions: Set(panc25)
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.184.135.215:54733]
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54733.
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/75/xqfxsstx5f70nqrv3pjt6llh0000gn/T/spark-15f3f4b7-2a90-451d-87d9-16d885a37dd9/blockmgr-efda35e0-f987-4460-b1aa-13e901f3fab5
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.1 MB
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /private/var/folders/75/xqfxsstx5f70nqrv3pjt6llh0000gn/T/spark-15f3f4b7-2a90-451d-87d9-16d885a37dd9/httpd-89de876f-f2f2-40c3-99a6-dceb3b8247e4
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 54734.
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/08/26 10:39:51 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
15/08/26 10:39:51 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4042.
15/08/26 10:39:51 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.184.135.215:4042
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54735.
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54735
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:54735 with 265.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 54735)
15/08/26 10:39:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

I am still not sure what went on when I had the problem.